# Create buffer based on the size of a line's length (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, buffer, qgis-modeler

I need to create a buffer around a point, witch has to be 1.3x bigger than the length of a given line.

I want to automate this process with graphical modeler or pyqgis. So the program should automatically read the line's length and create a buffer around this specific point.

[Edit]

This one process is going to repeat hundreds of times.
I will try to explain here all the steps that must be followed when the software runs the process only once:

1) The user must manually create a line and a point ( different shapefines and different tables). The line has the attribute length on its table.

2) The program should read the length of the line (created on step one) and create a buffer (with the radius 1.3x bigger then the line lenght) around the point (also created on step one).

So, these 2 steps consist one process. For each process, the user will create a new point and a new line. The line is only there to work like a rule. And the point is there to give the position for the buffer.

Comment: you mean the diameter of the buffer must be 1.3x the length of your line ? What do u want to automate - will u have many different cases to handle ?

Comment: The radious must be 1.3x the lenght of the line. I want to automate the creation of the buffer. I want the user to just create a point and a line , than the program must read the lenght of the line and create a buffer around this point. It's going to have hundreds of different cases.

Comment: how does the line relate to the point?

Comment: yeah but where are your data ? do u have a 'point' layer ? where is your line located ? in another table ? will it be always the same line ? give more details ! maybe there is an easier way than modeler or pyqgis ...

Comment: The line is only their to give the size of the buffer (radius).

Comment: I don't have the data yet, since the user is going to create the points and the lines. But the line and the points are going to be in different tables. Also, for every case, it's going to be a different point for a different line

Comment: so ... your aim is only to draw the same buffer of a given radius (given by your 'line' length) around all your points ?

Comment: the line shp has the attribute lenght. So the software should read this attribute and create a buffer 1.3x bigger around a point (different table and shp)

Comment: yeah but ... the same buffer for **all** the points of your points table ? or do u have only one point ?

Comment: No, I will try to explain. The user should create a point and a line. And the software needs to create a buffer. This process will repeat hundreds of times, with different points and different lines (each point will have their specific line). Each time the user will need to create a different point and line

Comment: We can imagine this working only once. So we can supose only one point and one line

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/318031/edit) and add all the information you gave in the comments and everything else we need to know. This makes it easier to give an answer to your question.

Comment: Can the user create the point and the line using the standard QGIS vector editing tools? Or are you trying to create something for a very unskilled user? Do you want to make a "wizard" style interface that says "Now click the point" and once that's done it says "Now draw a line" and then does the buffer? Your question is not clear.